# How to show iAd in all screens with single reference while using storyboard?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, iad

How can one implement iAd in such manner that it is implemented in only AppDelegate and can be used in all screens.

I put code in appDelegate.Do i still need to code for it in each view controller?

`AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [self addiAd];
    NSLog(@"window subview : %@",self.window.subviews);    //Here it shows no subview
    return YES;
}

-(void)addiAd
{
    self.adView.delegate = self;
    self.adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObjects:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape,ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait, nil];
    self.adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    [self setBannerFrame:orientation];
    self.adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] init];
    self.adView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 938, 768, 66);
    [self.window addSubview:self.adView];

}
-(void)removeiAd
{
    [self.adView removeFromSuperview];
}
-(void)setBannerFrame:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
        [self.adView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape];
        self.adView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 634, 320, 50);
    }
    else {
        [self.adView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
        self.adView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 890, 480, 32);
    }
}
```

All its delegate methods are also implemented in AppDelegate.m

What should be my next step? what am i doing wrong or missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya.  no need to write code in each view controll. here is my code

```
- (UIWindow *)viewControllerForPresentingModalView {

    return self;

}
- (void)adWhirlDidReceiveAd:(AdWhirlView *)adWhirlView {
    NSLog(@"Ad received");
    CGSize adSize = [adView actualAdSize];
    NSLog(@"Net work Name %@",[adWhirlView mostRecentNetworkName]);
    CGRect newFrame = adView.frame;
    newFrame.size = adSize;



    newFrame.origin.y=385;
    NSLog(@"frame size %f,%f",newFrame.origin.x,newFrame.origin.y);
    adView.frame = newFrame;




}
-(void)adWhirlDidFailToReceiveAd:(AdWhirlView *)adWhirlView usingBackup:(BOOL)yesOrNo
{
    NSLog(@"Ad not Received");
    NSLog(@"Net work Name %@",[adWhirlView mostRecentNetworkName]);
    CGRect tempFrame = adView.frame;
    tempFrame.origin.y = -adView.frame.size.height;
    adView.frame = tempFrame;


}
```

write all this methods in app delegate and in application didFinishedLaunching method just add the adwhirl view as a sub view of the window.

```
adView=[AdWhirlView requestAdWhirlViewWithDelegate:self];
    [self.window addSubview:adView];
```

Its working fine for me.

Comment: Finally I also did the same way.Added code to my AppDelegate & created methods called AddiAd & RemoveiAd which I called from each Viewcontroller's ViewWillAppear & ViewWillDisappear respectivly

Answer (score 2):

You don't need any of the iAd configuration in your app delegate, generally you configure it in the class for the view controller that it is displayed in - this means that *usually* you would need to place an ad view in every view controller that you wanted ads to be displayed in.

There are more simple methods, however - the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4918726/iad-multiple-uitableviewcontrollers), for example, provides a link to a [singleton class](https://github.com/larsacus/LARSAdController) that seems to do what you want - it provides a single class that manages your iAd configuration which you can then drop into every view that you want the ad to appear in.

Comment: This class seems very complex to reuse to make my own class with only some of its methods.Any other way?

Comment: You could subclass UIViewController and create/manage the adview in your class. You would then apply your class to your view controllers, and this is another way that means you only have to write ad-managing code once.

Answer (score 0):

Apple recommends creating it once in App Delegate, and sharing across all views.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2286/_index.html