# iAds for all iOS ViewController's

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, iad

**Hello**,
I have been searching for this specific/custom requirement all over the internet but could not find the solution for the same.
I want to integrate iAd's in almost all the views(SuperView's and SubView's) in my app.
Is there any way with which i can just use one iAd which would be common for all.
That is i need not write the same code for all the different views.
In a nutshell,a common iAD which would be available for all the view's in my app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Simple way :**  You need to integrate the ADWhirl SDK first. Then u need to add the adwhirl view in your root view controller as a sub view. Here is my code. i just added the adwhirl view controller to my tabbarview controller and made my tab bar controller as a rootview controller. so that my adwhirl view controller will display in all my view. Hope it will help u.

```
AdwhirlViewController *tabView  = [[AdwhirlViewController alloc] init] ;
    self.tabBarController =tabView;

    viewControllerFour.customDelegate=tabView;
    self.tabBarController.delegate = self;

    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    NSArray *multipleViewControllers=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:navControllerTwo,navControllerThree, navControllerFour,nil];

    [self.tabBarController setViewControllers:multipleViewControllers];

    [self.window setRootViewController:self.tabBarController];
```

Use this below link also:

[How to show iAd in all screens with single reference while using storyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12907803/how-to-show-iad-in-all-screens-with-single-reference-while-using-storyboard/12908704#12908704)

Comment: ADWhirl shouldn't be required for this to work. And you may want to explain how `AdwhirlViewController` actually works.

Comment: I believe the above answers are not correct as they have been marked as Down Votes. Please Let me know the correct way of doing so.             Thank You